# How to find my generated shared library from cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cmakelists-options

I want to create a shared library from `cmake` . I have a simple `test.cpp` .

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (test)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

#include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_library(test SHARED /home/tuhin/test/test1/test.cpp)
```

But I am not able to find `"test"` which my `.so`, I have seen  `test.dir` folder created but not `.so`

Please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: Are you running `make` after running `cmake`? CMake only generates the build scripts and then you have to run it to actually build your software. I assume you are using `make`, so, just run `make` in the same directory as you ran your `cmake` command.

Comment: Please provide the commands you used to run `cmake` and subsequently *build* the generated buildsystem (e.g. `make`). If the `.so` was not generated, it may be that you got errors at some point, so please include the **error logs** in your question post.

Comment: @Amir, exactly you got the right point , i was not running make so it was not generating. yesterday i got to know this

Answer (score 1):

(I suppose you read the comments and acted accordingly...)

(I also suppose you need a way to find out where your library will be placed, from within CMake build system)

The disk location of any target does not depend on `CMakeLists.txt` only, but also on the choice of the generator. Multi config generators like `Visual Studio something`, or `Xcode` might append configuration name as an additional directory,  so you may get different results just by choosing a different generator.

This means that there is no easy way to uniquely identify disk location during ***configure*** stage. On the other hand, you may very easily check that information during the ***build*** stage:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project (lib_file_name)
add_library(my_test_lib SHARED my_test_lib.cpp)

add_custom_target(output_lib_name 
  ALL 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "my_test_lib location: $<TARGET_FILE:my_test_lib>"
  )
```

note `add_custom_target` line:

- new target was added, named `output_lib_name`
- it will be executed as a part of building the default target (-> `ALL`)
- command to build this target is asking cmake to output the file name of the target in question, using CMAke generator expressions (--> `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "my_test_lib location: $<TARGET_FILE:my_test_lib>"`)

If you run it with makefile generator:

```
$ cmake -S /tmp -B /tmp/make-build -G "Unix Makefiles" ; cmake --build /tmp/make-build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/make-build
Scanning dependencies of target my_test_lib
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_test_lib.dir/my_test_lib.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libmy_test_lib.dylib
[100%] Built target my_test_lib
Scanning dependencies of target output_lib_name
my_test_lib location: /tmp/make-build/libmy_test_lib.dylib
[100%] Built target output_lib_name
```

Note the line

```
my_test_lib location: /tmp/make-build/libmy_test_lib.dylib
```

if you run it with Xcode generator:

configure:

```
$ cmake -S /tmp -B /tmp/xcode-build -G Xcode 

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/xcode-build
```

build release configuration:

```
$ cmake --build /tmp/xcode-build --config Release

........... lot of output deleted ...........

my_test_lib location: /tmp/xcode-build/Release/libmy_test_lib.dylib

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

build debug configuration:

```
$ cmake --build /tmp/xcode-build --config Debug

........... lot of output deleted ...........

my_test_lib location: /tmp/xcode-build/Debug/libmy_test_lib.dylib

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

Note how the location is different for different configuration builds, without any change in CMake build system.

At the end, this is the cmake documentation about [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), [cmake generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-queries).